# How to get bitbucket repository variables in my dockerfile and COPY them to my docker image like COPY bitbucket_variables /app

Tags: docker, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am sending my application code to bitbucket repo without .env file and enable bitbucket pipeline to build a docker image for my application through Dockerfile which is already in my repo.

But the issue is my build needs the .env file through out building the image and after building the image !! My image needs to have an .env file !!

I am trying to figure it out through bitbucket repository variables but maybe they are not available after building the image !! but i need them after building image

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker --env-file argument. With that you can give env file to docker while running it.

If you are using docker-compose or k8s, there are other ways to inject env variables to containers.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/